# Warning when method is too long?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, stylecop, resharper-7.1

I'm looking for a way to create a rule for StyleCop, Resharper, Visual Studio itself or at least a add in which show me a visual warning if a method is longer than X characters / longer than X lines.

Anyone some working solutions?

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you using? The Code Metrics feature of Ultimate will show you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very simple rule to create with StyleCop.  If you don't feel like rolling your own, [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/) includes such a rule that is configurable to your preferred maximum method length.

Comment: You are right this is very easy.